# Has anyone ever used a PHP ecommerce platform for backend/admin only, with a totally custom-built frontend utilising only the API of the platform?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, oscommerce, zen-cart

The title pretty much explains it.

I want to completely customise the shopfront, and working through the madness of files (eg, Magento) to do this would not be my cup of tea.

I do however still want the admin & calculation features of something like Magento - eg, Discount/Voucher codes, Sale Prices over predefined periods, Tax etc.

Has anyone done this before... and even if you haven't, can you recommend a platform which would be ideal in this situation?

I'm not keen on Magento due to lack of documentation and really poor performance on a standard webhost, even when just making an API call.

Cheers guys!

Comment: Perhaps a hosted solution like http://shopify.com/ would do you well in that case?

Comment: Not sure about Shopify. I wouldn't want the shopfront to be hosted by Shopify. They only allow 500 API calls every 300 seconds. I could foresee a single page load making more than 10 API calls.

Answer (score 5):

"Those that fail to learn Magento are doomed to reinvent it, badly."

Performance on Magento is a problem on shared hosting, however, on a modest virtual server, with caching on, there is no performance problem. With added tools, 'Varnish', 'Nginx' etc there is scalable performance. It works.

It is a pity that shops cannot be simple with a simple customers table, a simple products table, an orders table and blindingly fast performance. However, the Magento started from this (with OsCommerce), realised the problems/limitations and built a far more sensible system with the best programming methods. Despite their great work there are plenty of developers that think they can write a web shop in a weekend and bolt on requirements to it as needed. Tempting these 'noddy carts' are, they are not full featured or extensible in a modular fashion, as Magento is, therefore they are generally a complete waste of time.

I don't think that Magento documentation is as big a problem as you imagine. There is 'network effect' with Magento hence, a lot of the 'missing documentation' is Google-able.

Initially the layout engine and the 'millions of files' seems confusing. However, it takes a while to learn how this works and to get a few re-usable resources of your own. I think it is better to learn the Magento way of doing things, with modules, layout xml and MVC methods. Thinking you can format Magento blocks any better in a CMS such as Expression Engine and use Magento just for the backend will put you on a hiding to nothing, to end up with a fairly useless setup that isn't going to go anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your points. I wasn't planning to use any other CMS. I would have developed the shopfront completely myself. I have developed a couple of full e-commerce sites from the ground up before. Whilst this works, its hard to keep up with the features you require - hence my want to use an existing platform for the backend. However I want the flexibility to code and present however I like on the frontend, without all the bloat of Magento.

Assuming you disagree with this approach, is Magento the only option? Anyone used Lemonstand? Looks pretty good.